# Open source non-trivial SOA examples

Tags: soa

I've been looking for open source examples of SOA applications, but most of the times I find simple tutorial hello world style examples that introduce the tricks of the respective middleware.

Do you have any suggestion about any middle to big size example with multiple layers and/or governance ? Isn't it some kind of common example (a la Lena in image processing) for SOA ?

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is look at OpenESB:
http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=OpenESBIntroductionTutorial

Once you have a working example then you can look at extending it yourself, as you will have the tools to do that, and see how you can get applications to work together.

Are you trying to learn how to use SOA or do you want to look at an architectural diagram where it has been used in a complex system?

The introduction above is for learning to use it, via OpenESB, I don't know where you may find a diagram of a large example of SOA.

It may help if you could narrow your question down to what precisely are you looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

What I'm looking for an example application that it's slightly more complex than the typical 'hello world', 'basic loan' that most of the SOA infrastructures include, in order to reason about its architecture and design decisions.

I'm particularly interested about a 'real example' because most of the times you find the design or documents about the architectures but it's not normal to find an existing downloable implementation of the more sophisticated SOA architecture.

Do you know about any application like that ?

Comment: I don't know of any, mainly because there is so much to get it working, including setting up databases, creating webservices and populating them with the needed data.  But, if you go through a tutorial, have a test, then you can start to add more to it, and when you have problems you can ask. Once you have more experience then SOA design patterns begin to make sense, but in the beginning, just start to integrate through an ESB.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a detailed example you seek. If you are taking an approach of learning how to use SOA by checking examples, it may be a bad approach. You need to first know what and how you are going to do your SOA and then see what features are are enough for your needs.